# Magento - Free shipping over a time period

Tags: php, magento

We have a Magento Shop and the shipping settings are already set and everything works fine.

I would like to know if it is possible to set free shipping over a period without changing my shipping settings.

Example:
In May we would like to offer free shipping for all products.

But we dont want to change the shipping settings for this. Is this possible? Is there an extension for that oder is there a native solution from magento?

Comment: How many products do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a "Shopping Cart Price Rule" (in Magento admin under "Promotion"). There you can set a free shipping to "yes" and limit the price rule active period to whatever you like.

Comment: thanks.. thats exactly what i was looking for.. i wonder why i haven't seen this before >.<